# In electric system where is neutral line present?is it visible?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, electrical-distribution

In electric system is neutral point connected ground?If yes how it is connected to ground i cant see any such kind of connection?where it will be?

Comment: In a main panel not a sub. The neutral is the large conductor (same size as the hot legs) coming into the panel. There may be green grounds and white neutral wires connected to this buss. The ground is normally #6 copper, the 3 big wires in the panel 2 will go to the part that connects to the breakers.

Comment: Step one - what country are you in? Conventions vary hugely, so a north american answer might not apply at all, if you are in the UK or Europe or some other part of the world.

Answer (score 1):

In North American practice, neutral is connected to ground in **precisely one location**.  That is in the main panel, as close as possible to the current source.  The reasons for this are well answered elsewhere on this forum.

That closest point is considered the main panel.  Anything else fed from the main panel needs to keep ground and neutral totally separate.

Ground and neutral are not interchangeable.  They should not be tied together anywhere else.  Ground should never be used for current return.  Neutral should never be used as safety protection.  (Those who abuse ground are defeating its protection and wasting the wire.  If they are not serious about grounding, they should just not use grounding at all.  At least then, it will be obvious to electricians that their grounds are no good!)